# How to access devise sign_in in a service object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to move some code out of my controller and into a service object. How do I access the devise sign_in helper method from the service object.

```
class CompleteAccountRegistration

  def self.call(account_id, plan_id)
    @account = Account.find(account_id)
    self.create_user_account
    self.create_subscription(plan_id)
    sign_in(User.find(@account.owner_id))
  end
```

I am getting the following error in my tests.

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `sign_in' for CompleteAccountRegistration:Class
```

Comment: I have this issue. I tried adding `include Devise::Controllers::Helpers` to my service object but then I get `undefined method `helper_method' for UnimpersonateUser:Class`. I'm assuming I need to include something else too.

Comment: Anyone solved this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Including `Devise::Controllers::SignInOut` in your service object does the trick!

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work for me, still received: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'sign_in' for CompleteAccountRegistration:Class`

Comment: What version of Devise are you using? Maybe it's related to that.

Comment: Using `devise (3.4.1)`, added `include Devise::Controllers::SignInOut`